# Design an algorithm to calculate probability of team winning depending on variables

Tags: java, algorithm, math

so I am designing a football based game in Java where two teams will face off. Then I want to design an algorithm to calculate the probability of team A or team B winning depending on some factors.

1. The strength of the team (which doesn't change after being set)
2. The form the team is in (how many of their last 5 games they won or lost)
3. Some randomness so it can go either way even if team A is much stronger and in better form than team B.

I don't really know where to start though, any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Since Java is an OO language, you might start by designing a class to represent a team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a bit of OOP:

```
public class Team{
    private double /*int*/ strength;//Change the datatype, by your favors
    private double formOfLastFiveMatches;//0 for lost all, 1 for won all, 0.6 for won 3 of 5
    private Random random; //For the randomness
    //...Constructors, Getters,Setters
}
```

This is models your team.
Now start with calculating the match.

```
public class SoccerSimulator{
   private Team a,b;
   //...Constructors, Getters,Setters

   /**
   * Calculate the probability, that A wins.
   * @return the probability, A wins.
   */
   public double calculateProbability(){
      double strengthA = a.getStrength();
      double strengthB = b.getStrength();
      if(a.getForm() <= 0.2)
          strengthA *= (1 + (Math.random % 0.1));//Up to 10% bonus, because they won only 0-1 games in the last 5 games
      if(b.getForm() <= 0.2)
          strengthB *= (1 + (Math.random % 0.1));
      //Do something with the random number generator
      //....
      //TODO: Better algorithm
      double sum=strengthA + strengthB;
      return strengthA / sum;//Get the fraction A has in relationship to the sum.
   }
}
```

This is an quite basic algorithm, but you can use it as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear! Just wondering why you use "private Team a,b;", since that gives a NullPointerException? I understand that's because you haven't made the object yet, but why not use Team a = new Team(); for example? Still trying to learn haha.

Comment: You have to initialize the objects in the constructor.